# Not able to call A wcf rest service using javascript client Error: GET http://localhost:51348/TestService.svc/GetName?testvalue 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf, rest

Well I am pretty new to WCF services and I  know there are apparently too many questions and tutorials available but somehow I have not been able to get my java script client working.

I have a WCF Restful service running on my machine.I want to be able to call and fetch the values from the methods of the service. It has just one method **GetName** at the moment.But when I create the java script client I end up getting **Bad Request 400 error** Here is the Interface code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
   // [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "xml/{name}")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string GetName(string name);

}
```

Here is the implementation of the method in Service.cv.cs:

```
public string GetName(string name)
        {
            return "Hello:" + name.ToString();


        }
```

Here is my javascript client code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnSend").click(function () {
                    debugger;


                    var data = $("#txtName").val();
                    var name = "testvalue";
                   var _privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
                   var _publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
                   $.ajax({

                       type: "GET",

                       dataType: 'Xml',


                       url: 'http://localhost:51348/TestService.svc/GetName',

                       data: name,

                       success: function (result) {


                           result = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(result.documentElement);
                           alert(result);
                           //   alert("sucess");
                       },
                       error: function (xhr, err) {
                           alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                           alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                       }
                   });
                   return false;

                });

            });

        </script>
<body>
      <span>Name:</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <br />
    <br />


    <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Send" />


</body>
```

What am I doing wrong here?How should I call the functions of the service from javascript client and pass the parameters?? As at the moment it is generating BadRequest 400 error while  calling the service's function. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you open this endpoint in your browser?

Comment: @ Ricardo Pontual: Yes service runs just fine in the browser..

Comment: When I was try to call a service with xml response format, this link helped me, maybe it can give some valuable information:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1740583.aspx?Unable+to+consume+XML+response+from+WCF+REST+Service+in+JQuery